# Python split() return more characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, file

I have a `.txt` file and this is my lines:

```
1 word word \\123\\3456\\0000
```

the delimiter is `.split('\t')` and I expected the following list:

```
[1, 'word', 'word', '\\123\\3456\\0000']
```

but on my last character the split method is returning:
`'\\\\123\\\\3456\\\0000'` with two more `'\\'`

Does anyone know where is my mistake?

Comment: I dont see any issue with .split('\t'). Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Are you printing the resulting string (the last one)? Isn't it just a display issue? Try also printing its length.

Comment: Backslashes in strings need to be escaped... using another backslash. So instead of '\' you'll see '\\', and instead of '\\' you'll see '\\\\'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a representation of a string, double backslash means one backslash.

If you try to print it, it will appear correctly

```
>>> for i in s.split('\t'):
...     print(i)
... 
1
word
word
\\123\\3456\\0000
```

[String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: Thanks @pacholik I print out the list and it returns without the additionals double blackslash